# How to make one Twig macro template inherit another and be able to use macros in same namespace?

Tags: inheritance, import, macros, include, twig

Suppose I have two Twig templates containing just macros:

```html
<!-- macros_a.html.twig -->
{% macro help_icon(msg) -%}
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign nf-icon-help" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ msg }}"></i>
{%- endmacro %}
```

and

```html
<!-- macros_b.html.twig -->
{% macro hash(val) -%}
    <span class="nf-hash">{{ val }}</span>
{%- endmacro %}
```

In another template I want to use any of these macros like this:

```html
<!-- some_page.html.twig -->
{% import "@App/macros_b.html.twig" as macros %}

<p>Your hash: {{ macros.hash('90a11a5d3268') }}<p>

<p>This is some fuzzy text that needs a help icon. {{ macros.help_icon('Here is some helpfull text for you.') }}</p>
```

What I want is `macros_b.html.twig` to inherit the macros from `macros_a.html.twig` and make all macros accessible through one variable (`macros`).

The way I tried to solve this is to use something like `include`, `import`, `extends`, I think I tried every Twig function/tag that's somewhat related. I also tried to use `blocks` but that doesn't work neither. The macros in `macros_a.html.twig` just aren't available (Error message: `Attempted to call an undefined method named "gethash" of class ..etc..`).

Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inheritance possible with macros

Macros are made to do small generation content.

If you want something them to be available in everyscope independantly of the macro file, you should rather use custom [function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions)